# ng-select multiple checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-ngselect

When there are multiple checkbox options inside dropdown I don't want them to apply on each selection.

I would like to do like this : After checking few options, user has to click the apply button inside the dropdown then the options will get selected. If user doesn't click apply his selection will get reset.

[image]

Also I would like to show the selected option like this, instead of showing all the options inside the dropdown. If there is more than one option selected user will se (+1 other) or anything other text

[image]

The versions I'm using:

*Angular Version*: `7.3.7`,

*Ng-select Version*:`2.20`

Can anyone help?